# laravel | How to confirm which caching driver is being used?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I am trying to use `redis` in my application but I am not sure if my app is using `redis` or `file` driver as I can't create `tags` but I can create normal `keys` fine.

I have set `CACHE_DRIVER=redis` and also in my `cache.php` I have:

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

also in my database.php there is:

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

The reasons for my suspicion are I cannot create `tags` and running `redis-cli flushall` under `homestead(ssh)` does not seem to get rid of the cahce. I had to use Cache::flush() in laravel instead.

So How can I effectively find out which cache driver my application is using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its pretty simple , you can use redis cli monitor command to check the get/set are happening or not

```
redis-cli monitor
```

And try  to run the application .. if u able to see the keys then redis cache is running

u can also check the redis key by following command

```
redis-cli
```

Then enter following

```
keys *
```

I hope its useful.

Answer (score 5):

You should simply query your Redis DB like so:

```
redis-cli
```

Then, being on redis console:

```
SELECT <DB-NUMBER>

KEYS *
```

If you see some keys like

```
1) PREFIX:tag:TAG:key
2) PREFIX:tag:DIFFERENT-TAG:key
```

it is quite a hint that Laravel is using Redis as its cache backend. Otherwise, take a look at

```
<YOUR-APP-DIR>/storage/framework/cache
```

If you find some files/sub-folders in there, it is quite a hint, Laravel is using file-based caching.

Comment: Awesome for Select <DB-NUMBER>. I were debugging for 2-3 hours for this

Comment: Worked for me:
SELECT 1
keys *